# Pandas Time convert to business day time

Tags: python, date, datetime, time-series, datetimeoffset

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a Date column of the format datetime64[ns].

```
0        2016-10-19 23:41:03
1        2016-10-22 03:25:54
2        2016-10-21 23:58:05
3        2016-10-23 00:13:22
4        2016-10-22 00:51:26
5        2016-10-23 00:52:45
6        2016-10-23 02:18:42
```

Because of the specific type of project I am working on, I want to convert it so that the time is not based on regular days (0 am to 0 am) but to nightlife days (12 pm to 12pm). It means that if I do

```
data.dt.weekday_name
```

and get the weekdays based on the timestamps I get Monday going from Monday 12pm to Tuesday 12pm, and not from Monday 12 am to Tuesday 12pm as is it normally considered.

Is is possible to do it in Pandas ? Do you have a trick to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the answer :

```
data["Night_time"] = data["Day_time"] + datetime.timedelta(hours=12)

Night_time = 2016-10-20 11:41:03
Day_time = 2016-10-19 23:41:03
```

Which looks ok to me.

Is there a more elegant way ?